# Get-authenticodesignature always shows NotSigned

Tags: powershell, digital-signature

Anyone knows why get-authenticodesignature in powershell always shows the .dll or .exe file as **NotSigned** while it is showen as **signed** if I use the sigverif in the command prompt.

sigverif Output

```
    File                      Modified       Version             Status              Catalog              Signed By
------------------      ------------   -----------        ------------        -----------          -------------------
[c:\windows\system32]
batt.dll                 7/14/2009      2:6.1               Signed              nt5.cat             Microsoft Windows
```

PowerShell Output:

```
    PS> get-authenticodesignature C:\Windows\System32\batt.dll    

    Directory: C:\Windows\System32    

SignerCertificate                         Status                                 Path
-----------------                         ------                                 ----
                                          NotSigned                              batt.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a program in place to ensure that device drivers are reliable and unlikely to cause problems on your computer. When Microsoft developers and 3rd party vendors create a new driver it can be submitted to a special department within Microsoft for "device signing". The Signature is stored in the package of the driver in a cat file, that `sigverify.exe` check. for more explanations see [Driver Signing Requirements for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487317.aspx).

`get-authenticodesignature` is used to detect other executable signature, that is to say for .EXE, .DLL or .PS1. As far as PowerShell is concerned you can use `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` to sign your code. For .DLL and .EXE (whatever if they are native or managed) you can use [signtool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from SDKs or DDKs. The result can be shown in the properties of the file :

[image]

It exists another kind of signature, wich is only reserved to managed code. It's called a strong name. It's used to give an identity to an assembly. Signing an assembly with a strong name allow to verify it's unicity and allow to store it in the global assembly cache, it's done using [sn.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It can be conbinated with the preceding one.

Answer (score 2):

Normal files may be signed one of two ways: embedded signature, or catalog signing. See page 12 of [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653556(v=vs.85).aspx) for details about the two methods.

Get-AuthenticodeSignature works fine for files with embedded signatures; but it reports catalog-signed files as being unsigned. This has been [reported as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1121526/get-authenticodesignature-should-work-with-catalog-signed-files) to the PowerShell team, but apparently has not yet gotten enough upvotes to garner their attention.

As a workaround you can use Sysinternals [Sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441) which does properly handle catalog-signed files. There's a Powershell function called Use-Sigcheck in [this github code](https://github.com/bklockwood/Powershell-PKI/blob/master/VerifyProtectedDirs.ps1), it may come in handy for you.

Answer (score 1):

sigverif is used to find unsigned drivers and verify device drivers (under C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS). When you bring up the Dll's property page, do you see a 'Digital Signatures' tab?

Comment: No, the digital signature tab is not shown when i go to a the property windows of a file (system32/batt.dll for example)

Comment: I guess that's the reason why you get NotSigned. Try against another file that is digitally signed and you should get a Signed status

Comment: ..But if I use the **sigverif** tool it will show the file status [c:\windows\system32\batt.dll] as **Signed**. Please refer back to the first code block in my question. 
I tried on many .exe and .dll files and they all appear as **NotSigned** using **get-authenticodesignature** but thier status is **Signed** using sigverif.
Maybe this thing is related to this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=332314&SiteID=99